# How to change component's className according to its descendant's className in React?

Tags: reactjs, dom, classname

I have a React App that results to the structure similar to this:

[EDIT.: this is not a source code (which is not simply in one component), but rendered html (I believe it's sufficient for describing the problem)]:

```
<Component1 className="main-component1">
    <Something className="sub-component1"/>
    <SomethingDifferent className="sub-component2"/>
    <Something className="sub-component1"/>
</Component1>
<Component1 className="main-component1">
    <SomethingDifferent className="sub-component2"/>
    <SomethingDifferent className="sub-component2"/>
        <div className="popup"/>
    </SomethingDifferent>
    <Something className="subComponent1"/>
</Component1>
.
.
.
```

the `popup` is rendered only in specific situations. And I would like to change the `className` of its top parent (`Component1`) to be `className="main-component1 containsPopup"`. Any idea how to do that?

I was thinking about using [Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but I wasn't able to find a suitable use in this case.

Another idea was just to use some query filter to find it, but that doesn't seem to me like a nice approach.

I will be glad for any ideas ^_^

Comment: "*the popup is rendered only in specific situations.*" Is there any logic for that? Because with the current markup the popup is being always rendered.

Comment: Yeah, this was meant to be just an exemplary final html structure (not the generating code) to demonstrate it on something simple (whole code is huge).  `SomethingDifferent` might render for example some divs and an input and the popup is rendered only if that input is focussed.

Comment: Ok, because in that case you could reuse the logic for the rendering of the popup within the className string

Comment: How exactly please? I need to change the className only at `Component1` that has the `popup` as its descendant and not all `Component1`. Right now I can think about solutions that would change tha className for whole Class and not just a specific instance :/

Comment: Ahh, ok, I thought first that the `<Component1>` is being generated by a `.map` or something, but it's just manually placed multiple times

Comment: That is what I actually wanted to suggest initially (https://codesandbox.io/s/4jjp8pkk40)

Comment: Thanks for that! Unfortunately, I guess it won't be so easy :) the 'logic' that decides if the popup should show or not is not situated directly in the `component1` itself but in another component that is then rendered as a child (I mean grand-grand-..?..-grand-child) of the `component1`.